# Android Emulation Issue; Application working on ARM system image but not Intel Atom system image

Tags: android, canvas, android-emulator, intel

Being frustrated with the speed of the android emulator running on a ARM image, as soon as I discovered the intel atom image I used it right away. There was a immediate speed boost (boot going from 30 sec to 3 sec) but my application no longer works completely. All the XML portions of the app work, but as soon as I move to my activity which is all surfaceview and canvas work the screen goes black. It does not crash and there are no errors in logcat. The stranger thing is that I have a previously developed application which implements similar things (canvas and surfaceviews mostly) which works fine on the new image.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

System Information: Hardware: intel xeon quad core processor; 6 gb RAM, Nvidia 610 graphics card
OS: Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit

Comment: Have you tried "Use Host GPU" mode for the AVD?

Comment: I have tried using Host GPU and without, using my GPU helps speed the emulator up but the application still goes black in my main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well this somehow resolved itself (no idea how). If you run into this issue just be patient and keep developing in your ARM image for a while, then check the Intel image once every few minutes for me it just started working again after about 45 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Odd that it started working, I have found the "obj" folder doesnt get cleared out that well causing UI issues (generally didnt reflect changes I just made). So perhaps this was correctly deleted during a build which allowed it to start working correctly.