# Application fails to deploy to Android Intel emulator on API 19 (Platform 4.4.2)

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin.android, intel

### Problem:

*Update: I've been able to deploy my application to Android API Levels 10,15,17,18. So this appears to be a problem with API 19*.

When I try to debug my application (`MvvmCross` "Hello  World" app) it does not launch in the *Intel Atom (x86)* emulator, however the application does launch into the *ARM (armeabi-v7a)* emulator. When trying to launch in the *Intel Atom (x86)* emulator Visual Studio 2013 successfully starts up the emulator, does a build of the application, and then hangs after the build and says `Waiting for device...`, yet the emulator is up and running, is responsive, and appears to be working correctly. As soon as I close the emulator Visual Studio 2013 / Xamarin pops up this error:
[image]

The details simply say that the emulator was not found - so the environment is aware of the emulator and when it is running and when it is not running.

---

**Output from Visual Studio 2013 - Build Window**

`2>Build succeeded.
2>    0 Warning(s)
2>    0 Error(s)
2>
2>Time Elapsed 00:00:13.60
2>
2>
2>
2>Waiting for device..`

---

**Environment**:

- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Visual Studio 2013 Professional w/ ReSharper
- MvvmCross "Hello World" application
- Xamarin.Android

---

**Due Diligence**:

- At the command line when I run `adb devices` it shows the emulator is up and running.
- I closed and restarted Visual Studio 2013 & the emulator.
- I tried loading up the emulator first and then debugging but still had the same problem.
- Before I got this far I was having issues with the HAXM not being installed, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android) is not the issue I am having.
- I went through the [Xamarin setup instructions](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/configuring_the_x86_emulator/), and verified that the `x86` checkbox under Supported Architectures was selected. I even tried making it the only selection.
- I searched for solutions on the Xamarin forums, and [found someone who claims to have it up and running (asked him how)](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/46961/#Comment_46961), but found no answers to my issue.
- I searched for solutions here on Stack Overflow, but didn't find an answer.
  Neither [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125080/android-emulation-issue-application-working-on-arm-system-image-but-not-intel-a) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329068/using-intel-x86-atom-emulator) is the same problem I am having.
- I checked the `adb logcat`, but I can't really figure out if there is a problem there or not. The following chunk of text keeps repeating until I close the emulator.

  `D/AndroidRuntime( 2182): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
  W/linker  ( 2182): libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
  D/AndroidRuntime( 2182): CheckJNI is ON
  D/dalvikvm( 2182): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
  D/dalvikvm( 2182): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
  D/dalvikvm( 2182): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
  D/dalvikvm( 2182): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
  D/dalvikvm( 2182): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
  D/dalvikvm( 2182): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
  E/memtrack( 2182): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
  E/android.os.Debug( 2182): failed to load memtrack module: -2
  D/AndroidRuntime( 2182): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
  D/AndroidRuntime( 2182): Shutting down VM
  D/dalvikvm( 2182): GC_CONCURRENT freed 93K, 15% free 556K/652K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 1ms
  D/AndroidRuntime( 2194):`

---

**Configuration Details**

Here is the configuration of the Android Intel emulator [image]

Here are the properties of the Xamarin/MvvmCross Android project in VS2013:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the problem; I removed the old emulator and created a new one, but same result. However, it does install from Xamarin Studio.

Thanks Steve for mentioning that it works with API18; just downloaded that to confirm - and it works fine.

So the issue is somewhere with API19 or perhaps some other settings in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply creating a new emulator in the AVD Manager.

I have found that they get corrupted after a while and just stop working.

Can you successfully get a brand new Lvl 19 vanilla Android project running in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You should also try turning off snapshots for that particular AVD from with the AVD Manager. That fixed the issue for me running with an Intel Atom (x86) image.